# Jquery background color of li and checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to change the background color of li element to be changed when clicked. So when the user clicks on first li, the background color should be in red, and when he clicks second one, the second one should change to red, but the first one should go to white.

In short, the background color of selected li should be changed to show it is highlighted.

Also the checkbox should also be checked for only selected li.
I have tried to do like below. But it is changing for all selected li's..
Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://editor.webyana.com/javascripts/client_scripts/potential/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.gc").click(function () {

        $("li.gc").each(function (i) {
            $("li.gc[i]").css({
                backgroundColor: '#FFA700'
            });
        });
        $(this).css({
            backgroundColor: '#000000'
        });

        $(this).children("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', 'checked');

        //do something with the sortcat
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="gc">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            Check1
            <a>Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="gc">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                Check2
                <a>Link2</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="gc">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                Check3 Link3
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="gc">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                Check4 Link4
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than mucking with the css function, I would suggest you use classes in CSS and simplify the logic a bit. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCKdk/).

```
// store this for later use. only search once!
var items = $("li.gc");

items.click(function() {
    // again, only need to run this once - cache the selector!
    var item = $(this);
    // remove the selected class and uncheck all the inputs for all items
    items.removeClass("selected").find("input").removeAttr("checked");
    // add the selected class and check the input
    item.addClass("selected").find("input").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

---

And just for your reference, here is your original code idea (using `.css()`) expanded:

```
$("li.gc").click(function () {
    $("li.gc").css({
        backgroundColor: '#FFA700'
    });
    $(this).css({
        backgroundColor: '#000000'
    });

    $(this).children("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', 'checked');

    //do something with the sortcat
});
```

When you use `.css()` as a setter, it operates on all matched items.

Answer (score 1):

First define a "red" class in your css.

```
.red {
       background-color: red;

    }


$("li.gc").click(function() {
    // Then on-click remove it from all at first
     $("li.gc").removeClass("red");
    // and add it to the clicked one

    $(this).addClass("red");

});
```

Comment: bt gc is the class name i hve set to all the li elements.. so how is it possible??

Comment: @user662503: elements can have more than one class.

Answer (score 1):

Uku Loskit's answer is in the right direction. But, to address why your original idea is not working, it is because `li.gc[i]` is not the correct CSS selector: it looks for all `<li />` tags with the `gc` class _and which have an attribute named `i`, since `[foo]` is the CSS selector for tags that have the `foo` attribute.

Here is some code that probably does what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("li.gc").click(function () {
      // Reset all <li />s with the .gc class to white
      $("li.gc").css("background-color", "white");

      // But now set the one that was just clicked to red.
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");

      // Similarly uncheck all checkboxes
      $("li.gc input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", false);

      // But now check the checkbox child of the just-clicked <li />.
      $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try it in-one with a [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/), Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$("li.gc").click(function(){
  $(this)
     .css('background-color','#f00')
     .siblings()
     .css('background-color','#fff');  
});
```

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vr8yJ/)**

update:

use radiobuttons for single selection

```
  <li class="gc">
        <input type="radio" name="groupname" />
        Check1
        <a>Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="gc">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="groupname"  />
            Check2
            <a>Link2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="gc">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="groupname"  />
            Check3 Link3
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="gc">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="groupname" />
            Check4 Link4
        </div>
    </li>
```

script like:

```
$(".gc").click(function(){
  $(this)
     .css('background-color','#f00')
     .siblings()
     .css('background-color','#fff')
     .end()
     .find(':radio')
     .attr('checked','checked'); 
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vr8yJ/5/)

Comment: I still think using classes is better than setting css... but the `.siblings()` trick is pretty nice +1...

Comment: Oh - and here's an update with the checkbox functionality and the chain... http://jsfiddle.net/vr8yJ/1/

Comment: @gnarf, use radiobuttons for that, not checkboxes